# sass compass import not in compiled css

Tags: sass, gruntjs, compass-sass, compass

I am running sass 3.4.2 and compass 1.0.1 and compiling compass with grunt-contrib-compass.

I am importing Zurb Foundation scss files into a master stylesheet, but a few of the imports do not appear in the compiled css. After digging deeper, it seems like if there is an error in the @import file that the error is not reported.

My grunt task config code looks like this:

```
compass: {
    dist: {
        options: {
            require: [],
            httpPath: '/',
            http_images_path: '/assets/images',
            importPath: 'public_html/assets/bower_components',
            cssDir: 'public_html/assets/css',
            sassDir: 'public_html/assets/_src/scss',
            imagesDir: 'public_html/assets/images',
            javascriptsDir: 'public_html/assets/_src/js',
            outputStyle: 'compressed',
            noLineComments: true
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was related to the @export mixing being broken. It can be fixed by rolling back to previous version of sass and compass or by editing the foundation source code.

Please see these fixes:

http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/18624-foundation-5-and-compass-10
https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/5636
https://github.com/zurb/foundation/pull/5632/files